# Machine learning model with varying input shape as time changes

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I am trying to predict the bookings of a stand-up comedian cafe. There are a lot of features I can use which have an affect on the number of sales. (e.g. day of the year, weather, average sales last month, day of the week, average sales on the specific day of the week etc.)

However, one of the features that most correlates with the actual number of sales is the number of tickets already sold before the deadline. The customers are able to start making reservations 120hours (5 days) before the actual deadline of ordering (11:00 AM on the same day of the show).

I would prefer to use this data as input for my machine learning algorithm. Currently I created 120 columns in the dataframe. The columns define 120 hours before deadline untill the deadline itself. Column "hour_98" therefore shows the accumulated sales 4 days before the deadline. Column "hour_24" shows the accumulated sales 24 hours before deadline etc.

If I now would like to predict the sales 24 hours before deadline the columns "hour_24" until "hour_0" are all given "NaN" values. Since algorithms can't deal with NaN values **I currently give these columns a value of 0**. However, I tihnk this is too simplistic and will result in bad prediction model.

How do we deal with a changing input shape since we obtain more data if we get closer to the deadline of ordering?

Answer (score 1):

Now from what I understand, you have a fixed number of columns, each representing the data from a predefined hour before the deadline. So in a sense the input data shape never changes, only the validity of some input features changes.

Provided you have a fixed input shape, with changing validity of the features (NaNs),
you can get around that issue by using a mask for each input feature.

For example a valid `hour_24` can be represented as `hour_24 = 20` and `mask_24 = 1`, and an invalid `hour_24` can be represented as `hour_24 = 0` (or whatever) and
`mask_24 = 0`.

The algorithm itself will need to learn where to ignore a given feature in respect to the related feature's mask.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55423706/11922936) explains in more detail how to mask input.